# How to send xmlhttp POST request with captcha input?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I intend to capture a captcha image and show it to the user in an Excel form for input, send it back to server with other needed data, then parse the response HTML for the data I need.

DISCLAIMER: I'm not trying to bypass the captcha, since the user will still have to read and input it, Instead I'm trying to only automate a few clicks and Copy/Paste. This is not maliciously intended.

The site is: http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao.asp

I get captcha information, save it and show it to the user, without any problems so far. I also get the cookie information in this part of the code:

```
Dim WinHttpReq As New XMLHTTP60
Dim Docweb As New HTMLDocument
Dim IE As Object
Dim corpo As String
 Const adTypeBinary = 1
 Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

    '\\Get Captcha Image data stream and Session Cookie data
    url = "http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/captcha/gerarCaptcha.asp"
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", url, False
    WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "image/png"
    WinHttpReq.send
    Oimg = WinHttpReq.responseBody
    Ocookie = WinHttpReq.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")

    '\\To create the png file
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    oStream.Open
    filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "captcha.png"
    oStream.write Oimg
    oStream.savetofile filepath, adSaveCreateOverWrite

    '\\PNG show on this form activation
    Load FrmCaptcha
    FrmCaptcha.Show
```

After the user types the captcha, this is the code to POST and where I'm getting stuck:

```
CNPJ = 00000000000191
url = "http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/PessoaJuridica/CNPJ/cnpjreva/valida.asp"
WinHttpReq.Open "POST", url, False
WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "flag=1; _ga=GA1.3.1119390031.1461615099; nova_visita_ano=a27de975-d212-bd09-8afe-66e1675887f1; nova_visita_mes=a27de975-d212-bd09-8afe-66e1675887f1; " & Split(Ocookie, ";")(0)
WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WinHttpReq.send "origem=comprovante&cnpj=" & CNPJ & "&txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br=" & FrmCaptcha.TextBox1.Value & "&submit1=Consultar&search_type=cnpj"
Debug.Print WinHttpReq.Status
pag = WinHttpReq.responseBody
corpo = WinHttpReq.responseText
```

The variable CNPJ in this code is for testing only. In the original code the macro loops through the data put in a column.

Then I run IE to check the responsetext (only test phase):

```
Set IE = CreateObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
IE.Navigate "about:blank"
IE.Visible = True
IE.Document.write corpo
```

And finally write to HTML document to parse the response:

```
Docweb.body.innerHTML = corpo

'\\Here comes the Code to parse the HTML, which is not problem
```

Problem is that the server response for the POST request is not the expected one. It is not the same as if I entered the data in the site and clicked the submit form.

I don't know if it has to do with cookie session, or has to do with the Jscript that site runs when the form is submitted manually:

```
<form id="theForm" action="" onSubmit="javascript:return Submeter();" method="post" name="frmConsulta">
```

Jscript:

```
function Submeter()
        {
            document.cookie = 'flag=1';
            if (validaCaracteresCaptcha('theForm', 'txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br', 'valida.asp') == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And:

```
function validaCaracteresCaptcha(nomeForm, idLetra, paginaDestino) {
            var form = document.getElementById(nomeForm);
            if (document.getElementById(idLetra).value == "")
            {
                 AlertaCaptcha("Favor preencher algum o campo de validação");
                 form.action= "";
                 return false;
            }
            //if (document.getElementById(idLetra).value != "" && document.getElementById(idSom).value != "")
            //{
            //   AlertaCaptcha("Favor preencher apenas um dos campos de validação");
            //   form.action="";
            //   return false;
            //}
            if (document.getElementById("cnpj").value == "")
            {
                 AlertaCaptcha("Favor preencher o campo de CNPJ");
                 form.action="";
                 return false;
            }
            form.action=paginaDestino;
            return true;
        }
```

How to deal with these Jscrip validations? Are they needed? Is the cookie data sent correct? Is the problem somewhere else?

Other important information: The captcha is generated on access, meaning it changes on every request, not having a "src" or unique url id associated with it.

I think it is not the problem if the cookie validation is right, since this code requests it only once, sending its result input string later.

Another problem is if I test and stop the code to the point after the code gets the cookie information, trying to run the code again generates error on "Ocookie" variable, since VBA links to the previous session and sends the already stored cookie data. How do I reset this by code?